# 8051 behaves differently with two similar programs

Tags: 8051, c51

I am trying to drive relays with a 8051. For this, P2 is connected to Darlington array ULN2803A, and relays are connected to the corresponding outputs of ULN2803A.

First, I tried to test if the circuit is working, with this very simple code:

```
#include <at89c51cc03.h>

void main()
{
    P2 = 0xFF;
    while (1)
    {
    }
}
```

Nothing happened. Then I found this code on Keil's website, to drive relays again:

```
#include <reg52.h>

#define relayport P2

void Delay_ms(int);

void main()
{
  do
  {
    relayport = 0xFF; //All relays On
    Delay_ms(1000);
    relayport = 0x00; //All relays Off
    Delay_ms(1000);
  }while(1);
}

void Delay_ms(int k)
{
  int j;
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<k;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<100;j++)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

This worked, for some reason... the relays started ticking on and off.

Question is, why didn't the first code work? I expected the first code to turn and keep the relays on. The variant is AT89C51CC03.

---

Edit: The same faulty behavior is observed when I did the following, intending to turn the relays on and off once:

```
void main(){  
    relayport = 0xFF; //All relays On
    Delay_ms(1000);
    relayport = 0x00; //All relays Off
    Delay_ms(1000);
  while(1);
}
```

Very weird... Does anybody know what should be done in the case which I want to toggle the relays once, then enter the superloop?

---

Edit 2: It looks like it is a very specific bug, because the program is also behaving normally on software debugger. I will report to Keil.

Comment: Why is `reg52.h` included in one and `at89c51cc03.h` in the other? That could make quite a lot of difference, depending on the content of those files...

Comment: Depends on the circuit. Are you sure that with your circuit relays should turn on when P2 is high? Change `P2 = 0xFF;` to `P2 = 0x00;` and see the difference.

Comment: @Bregalad the example code included the former header. But SFR definitions are the same, so this shouldnt be much of a problem

Comment: @Anonymous it is the same, no reaction... Could posting the generated assembly code help?

Comment: Did you try to also do the on/off cycling in your version of the code ? Just a random guess but maybe the first write happens too soon after the voltage is established and the relay can't switch yet... ?

Comment: You say 8051 but I very much doubt you have a 1980 chip. What is the exact part number of your MCU?

Comment: @TonyM as told, it is AT89C51CC03

Comment: Look at the assembler. This is a problem with your code/compiler.

Comment: Your micrcontroller (MCU) has only deliver 50 uA out of its quasi-bidirectional I/O ports when driving high. It's actually a pull-up resistor and a FET to GND within the MCU. Your ULN2003A needs more drive current than that, regardless of your present problem. I strongly recommend you completely rule this out now by connecting a 2K7 pull-up from P2.x to Vcc (which I assume is 5V though doesn't matter). That's about 8x stronger drive current.

Comment: I would verify that Delay_ms() is generating the delay you expect it to, or replace it with your own delay loop.  The library code may assume a different clock speed than your actual 8051 is using. Your first code won't work if the relay drivers are active low, not active high.

Comment: "First, I tried to test if the circuit is working, with this very simple code:... Nothing happened" - you measured the voltages on the port pins, and they all stayed at 0V?

Comment: @BruceAbbott indeed. The circuit was behaving oddly too, like sometimes when I touched the terminals with voltmeter probes, the relay went on. But totally random.

Comment: As per my much-earlier comment: did you put a 2K7 pull-up on the I/O pin? What happened when you did?

Comment: @TonyM , I couldnt, because it is a PCB, and probably a previously tested one, with the same uC, relays and driver.

Comment: Up to you. Sounds like you've decided that's not a problem area, despite your note about instability to a scope probe. I'll leave you to it.